# Can't get printf() or echo to work properly in php

Tags: php

Like the title says, I'm having a hard time getting the `printf()` and `echo` parts of my code to output their text properly.

Here's the first page, a simple form:

```
<form action="WhoYouAre.html" method="post">
        <Label>Name: <label><input type="text" name="name"><br>
        <Label>Age: <label><input type="text" name="age"><br>
        <Label>Address: <label><input type="text" name="address"><br>
        <Label>State: <label><input type="text" name="state"><br>
        <Label>Sex: <label><input type="text" name="sex"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

And here's the code for the page that's supposed to display the information:

```
<?php
    session_start(); ?>
    <?php
    $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
    $_SESSION['age'] = $_POST['age'];
    $_SESSION['address'] = $_POST['address'];
    $_SESSION['state'] = $_POST['state'];
    $_SESSION['sex'] = $_POST['sex'];

    printf("Your name is %s.
    Your age is %d.
    Your address is %s, in the state of %s.
    Your gender is %s.", $_SESSION['name'], $_SESSION['age'],
    $_SESSION['address'], $_SESSION['state'], $_SESSION['sex']);

    if($_SESSION['sex'] == 'male')
        echo "<body style='background: url(http://images.mentalfloss.com/sites/default/files/styles/article_640x430/public/4hjh3kj634.png)'>";

    echo file_get_contents("PostPage.txt");
    ?>
```

Here's what is output to my page.

```
"; echo file_get_contents("PostPage.txt"); ?>
```

Any tips??

Answer (score 0):

You are posting your form to a `.html` file:

```
<form action="WhoYouAre.html" method="post">
```

While it can be set, by default `.html` files are not parsed and executed as PHP source files, so it will return its content unmodified. You will need to use the `.php` extension instead.